# Is there a good iPhone app which syncs with Google docs?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, google-docs

I'd like to be able to write notes on my iPhone and have them synced with my Google docs. I've tried Notemaster, but it doesn't always work (some docs just generate an error message when I try to sync). Is there something out there that is more reliable?

Comment: I'm looking for something to pull down many of my google docs to my iPad so I can edit them on the go and then sync later when I'm back home (or somewhere w/ wifi).  Seems the two apps to check out are Awesome Note and NoteMaster? What would happen if you're ready to sync back but a doc has been edited elsewhere? This would all happen in the background? (I wouldn't have to remember to start up the app each time I'm back home)

Comment: @Shahryar - I don't know how any of the apps handle merge conflicts; it's very likely the last revision synced becomes the actual version. As for working locally without a net connection and syncing when one is available, I believe they all allow it, though word on the street is that Google will soon launch an HTML5 replacement for their now-defunct Google Gears technology. The new system sounds even better, providing not just local storage of documents on disconnected devices, but also for full Docs functionality locally, syncing when possible.

Comment: @Shahryar - I turned your answer into a comment, as it was asking new questions instead of answer @Rob's question. Please consider creating a new question, as you'll be much more likely to get a response.

Answer (score 4):

### [Awesome Note](http://bridworks.com/anote/en/main/index.php)

It syncs well with Google Docs. It also syncs with EverNote. It's feature rich and very polished. I love it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com)?  It's a great little app that is on just about everything, syncs notes and allows you to edit on the go.

Comment: I love Evernote, but I don't think it syncs with Google Docs?

Comment: Nope, but to the best of my knowledge (which based on the answer below me isn't that good) there isn't anything that syncs google docs.  Evernote is already established as a very portable document syncing system.

Answer (score 1):

#### [NoteMaster](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notemaster-notes-images-synced/id297921531?mt=8)

Late to the party, but I've been using NoteMaster for a year or so now. It syncs with Google Docs effortlessly, I'm very pleased with it.

That said, Awesome Note looks a lot nicer, clearly has many more features, and costs the same.

Answer (score 0):

More recently, you can use [Google Docs for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/google-docs/id842842640?mt=8), Google's official app for accessing your Google Docs. It supports Offline Docs so you can edit them without an internet connection.